# How to use jquery 1.9.1 instead of jquery 1.4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am using rails 3.2 and default jquery is using is 1.4 but I want to use default jquery 1.9.1, How can I do it.

I have tried

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js" %>
```

But I dont want to include it with `javascript_include_tag` and download everytime from internet.

When I copied this code into assets/jquery_1.9.1.js file and load it but Jquery slider is not working with it. No displaying slider.

Comment: @MikeW; When I copied this code into assets/jquery_1.9.1.js file and load it but Jquery slider is not working with it. No displaying slider.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17345961/29489 check out this answer. it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

When jQuery 1.9 was released a number of deprecated features were removed that existed in earlier versions. It is likely that your slider requires some of these earlier features.

jQuery Migrate is a plugin that identifies these deprecated features and restores the function if necessary. You can get jQuery Migrate [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme)